# moving magento1.9 from one to another server

Tags: magento-1.9, database, server-setup

i moved magento 1.9 from one server to another server, but it is not working giving error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

[image]

for admin panel it is showing url not found.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working as suggested in answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your **MySQL user (root)** does not have `localhost` access to the database. (the server itself).

Firstly you need to login to *mysql from the command-line* with your *root user*:

`mysql -u root -p -h IP.Address.Of.DB -P PortNumber`

***It is never a good idea to use the root user for db access! Create a new mysql user***

- You need to create a new MySQL user and grant access to the database:
  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newdbname.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
- Also if you need to remotely access it, (for instance from a Mysql Client from your work desktop)

*Specific IP only:*
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newdbname.* TO 'username'@'ip'`;

**OR**

*Any IP:*
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newdbname.* TO 'username'@'%'`;